# I am trying to use "return" statement in Python it is not working.

Tags: return, python-2.7

I am trying to use the return statement. If the y is negative then program will terminate. But it is showing "ValueError: math domain error"

```
import math
y=-5
def df(y):
if y<=0:
        print y, "is negative"
        return
result = math.log(y)
print "The log of y is",result
```

Comment: where are you calling your function from?

Comment: You should edit your question so it doesn't get downvoted into oblivion.  Spelling, grammar, and punctuation are all important.  Make sure you read the editor tips so you understand how to use code blocks in posts (prepend each code line with 4 spaces).  Remember, if you don't put any effort into asking your question, people won't put any effort into answering it.  Welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: well, since you are new, you can read the FAQ about format first, and I dont think that is specific enough as a quesiton. link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: If you are asking about your df() function then your example should show you trying to use it. You define it. But then you go and use the math module. Can you tell is specifically what you expect to happen?

Comment: if there is nothing after `return`, your function will not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return is empty....there is no variable name or value on the same line with "return". For example, if you wanted to return the value 5, you'd put

```
return 5
```

If you wanted to return a variable foo, you'd put

```
return foo
```

Right now you are returning nothing.

Maybe you want this?

```
import math
y=-5
def df(y):
    if y<=0:
        print y, "is negative"
        return "impossible to calculate"
    result = math.log(y)
    return result

print "The log of y is", df(y)
```

Comment: while using this code it is showing "return"outside the function.it is happening for line 8

Comment: Edited. I like perl better so I use it more often and forget these strict formatting things.

Comment: Thanks PinkElephantsOnParade for ur help

Answer (score 2):

I have this feeling you wanted to include your log call inside the df() function and just check it for negative first.

```py
import math
y=-5
def df(y):
    if y<=0:
        print y, "is negative"
        return
    result = math.log(y)
    return result

print "The log of y is", df(y)
```

To have your function return a value you have to specify what it should return. Otherwise it returns None

Comment: Ah, come to think of it maybe that is what he wants - this makes the most sense, at least - minus the fact that he'll be taking log of NoneType if y is negative.

Comment: Ya I wanted to make the most minimal change possible to the code just to address the specific problem and not introduce too much new stuff

Answer (score 1):

Return transfers control back to the caller.  In this case, if you wanted to get the value of the function, you would need to call it, and you would need the function to actually return something.  Perhaps something along these lines:

```
import math

def df(v):
    if v <= 0:
        print v, "is negative"
        return

y = -5
df(y)
result = math.log(y)
print "The log of y is",result
```

Though I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.  If you wanted your function to return something, you would use this syntax:

```
return [something]
```

... replacing [something] with the value or variable whose value you want to return.  math.log returns the logarithm of its argument.  You already know how to save the return value of a function:

You expect this to cause the program to exit.  Returning will only exit the program if used from the main method, i.e. outside of any functions.  Return gives control back to the calling routine (if there is no calling routine, the program exits).  You would want to use the exit call instead:

```
import sys
...
sys.exit(0)
```

`sys.exit` will immediately terminate the program, passing the provided value back to the calling program.  If you do not know what this is, you can use the value 0.

```
result = math.log(y)
```

As for your error message, you can't take the logarithm of a negative number, try a positive one instead. (not 0 either)

I think you want something like this:

```
import math

def df(v):
    if v <= 0:
        print v, "is negative"
        return True # returns true if the value is negative or zero
    return False    # otherwise returns false

y = -5
if df(y):           # test if negative or positive, branch on return value
    return          # if value was negative or zero, return (exit program)
result = math.log(y)
print "The log of y is",result
```

Comment: I am tring to use the return statement for the program to terminate and print the result that y is not positive. If y is negative

Comment: You can't exit the program by returning from a function you called.  I'll add another edit for what you want to be doing.

Comment: Wug,ur code is giving a syntax error,for line 11.I am reading a book,Learning with Python, there the program I wrote was given. It was suppose to exit and print the error message if the value of y is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Any function needs 3 parts, as I learned for programming:

(1) input, as you "def" a function, you need to know what you want to put into the function.

For example:

```
def function (input1, input2):
```

We also called those inputs as **parameters**.

**(2) you need to show the output:**

For example, on the code you provide, if you want to return the number that variable "result" holds, you can do:

```
return result
```

or if you do not want to return, or output, anything, you can do:

```
return None
```

In python, None means nothing, at least you can think it that way for now.

(3)Function is doing things for you, so the things between

```
def function(inputs):
```

to

```
return None
```

is what you have to modify the variable from inputs into return (or output).

Hope it helps, and always work before ask any question. Good luck on Python